# What was the slot for in the 1950's slotted bricks?

Tags: piece-information, history

[Bricklink has a list of ancient bricks from the 50s that have slots in them.](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=423) What was the purpose of the slot? Its positioning on various pieces suggests that there was something specific you were supposed to put there — a window, maybe?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh, I should have read further down the page. There were special panes of "glass" in frames that fit the slots.

[image]